# Keeping child elements horizontally aligned according to its container, and still aligned left according to the other child elements, on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the elements to be aligned centered on their container on window resize, like this:

```
-----------child1--child2----------
-----------child3-----------------
```

See that the child elements are horizontally aligned center to their container, but they are aligned
left according to themselves( Using flexbox justify-content flex-start), (see child3 for example is aligned left);
When I resize the window the child elements must remain aligned centered according to its container but aligned left themselves.

How could I do that? Is that possible?

Here is a sample to something close to what I want:

http://jsfiddle.net/z8nxf5w3/193/

Comment: Can you post your HTML so far? Hard to visualize it.

Comment: There you go sorry

Comment: @I.R.R., did you get it?

Comment: Just saw your fiddle. It is unclear to me how your requirement is different to the one in the fiddle. Like this?: http://jsfiddle.net/axkm0p3y/2/

Comment: @Venkat, hi the elements inside (child elements) must be aligned themselves left but center according to its container. That fiddle is close, but the elements must align center on resize window. You can see that the child elements get a little bit too much to the left, as you increase the container size

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: The child  elements must be centered according to their container on resize

Comment: @MaxBaldwin, hi Max, didn´t find nothing usefull there, nothing useful to this post

Comment: `flex-direction: column`: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#article-header-id-3

Comment: Hi @MarceloNoronha, please include a [mcve] in your question itself. Adding a link to JSFiddle is helpful but not adequate on its own.

Comment: I could offer a website example, but the jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/z8nxf5w3/193/) , is resumed and straight to the point, without unused code. Even if I try to make a website example, it would take too unrelated content.

Comment: Well, you can see the original idea from this website: http://br418.teste.website/~noron298/bra/teevo What I want is that the footer elements (lists) align center according to its container on window resize, and aligned left according to the other lists elements Please, see the page using a mobile screen resolution like max width 480px

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are centering them with `margin: auto` in the divs, and still trying to make them align left in the .wrapper.

Apart from removing `margin: auto`, I removed the min-width. You should handle this via media queries if you want to center in the wrapper yet align left. 
Why? The way you center things in the wrapper is by making them fill it up completely (except for the padding that you define). I created to sample options: 3 and 2 elements per row. If you calculate margins and widths in percentages, you can make them fill up the entire wrapper.

Here's a working option:

```css
.container{
  padding:30px;
  background-color:green;
  text-align:center;
}
.wrapper{
   padding:30px;
  background-color:yellow;
   display:flex;
   justify-content:flex-start;
   flex-wrap:wrap;
   margin:auto;
   width:40%;
}

.wrapper div{
  
  /*min-width: 100px; --> don't use this, use % and media queries */
  width: 31.3%;
  margin: 5px 1%; /* 31.3 * 3 + 6 * 1 = 99.9% */
  background-color: #eee;
  /* margin-right:auto; --> this centers the elements
  margin-left:auto; */
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .wrapper div{
    width: 48%; /* 2*48 + 4 = 100% */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="child-1">
      text1
      </div>
      <div class="child-2">
      text2
      </div>
      <div class="child-3">
      text3
      </div>
      <div class="child-4">
      text4
      </div>
      <div class="child-5">
      text5
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That´s cool, but the elements should have a maximum and minimum size. So they can make more rows on increase container, and get more columns on decrease container

Comment: In that case you will have to choose: They're either aligned in the center, or the left of the container. You can't have it aligned in both ways...

Comment: Got it thank you
Here is the fiddle with max-width and min-width:
http://jsfiddle.net/z8nxf5w3/103/
@Victoria Ruiz, wouldnt be possible using onresize event in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I created a copy of your fiddle as per my understanding. Will try to help based on your need based on this. Let me know.

I think `text: center` property for your container is causing the issue.

Check this: `http://jsfiddle.net/z8nxf5w3/98/`

Comment: The only problem with that is that the child elements that get a new column get centered horizontally, they should be aligned left according to the child elements, and center according to its container as I ilustrated in my question post, see 'child3" position

Comment: This is the closest I can get:
http://jsfiddle.net/z8nxf5w3/112/
Though you can see, that the elements are not aligned center on container resize

Comment: I'm trying something like this:
Last edit:
http://jsfiddle.net/z8nxf5w3/130/
Still the second line/column of the elements is aligned center. I´d like it to be aligned left, according to the child elements, and center according to its container

Comment: This is my last attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/z8nxf5w3/193/
Try to resize the window